# Iterating through sequence of Images in tensorflow

Tags: batch-file, tensorflow, iteration

I have a database with images numbered from 1 till 7500.

I need to feed these images into my model in tensorflow in the following manner:

grab the 1st 100 images, that is, from 1 till 100, then grab another 100 images such that the next batch is from 1 till 101. As well, the following batch is from 2 till 102 and so on...

The purpose for using the following behavior is that I am using a recurrent neural network where the images to be fed are faces detected from a video. Therefore, I need to feed sequences of images such that these images are directly following one another.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a perfect solution for your question, but this one might help you.

I'm assuming that you are using tfrecords to build inputs because if not, feeding numpy to model doesn't meet this problem.

supporing your image files are list like this `["image_0", ..., "imgae_N"]`, you can build i-th  `tf.example` with `["image_i", ..., "image_i+100"]` as a feature.
After dequeuing, you get a tensor contains the names of there images, and then unstack them, read image content from there image names with `tf.read_file` and decode them to images with `tf.image.decode_image`, and concat them back into one tensor and send it to your model as  input.